# Calling a parent's method from the child

Tags: ruby

Some code

```
class Parent

  def print
    p "Hi I'm the parent"
  end
end

class Child < Parent

  def initialize(num)
    @num = num
  end

  def print
    child_print
  end

  def child_print
    if @num == 1 
      #call parent.print 
    else
      p "I'm the child"
    end 
  end
end

c1 = Child.new(1)
c2 = Child.new(2)
c1.print
c2.print
```

`Child` is an instance of `Parent`. `Print` is the method exposed in the interface, and both classes define them. `Child` decides to do other things in a (possibly really complex) method, but will invoke its parent's method under some condition.

I could just write

```
  def print
    if @num == 1 
      super
    else
      p "I'm the child"
    end 
  end
```

And that works, but what if it's not just a simple one-liner comparison but instead is doing lots of complicated things that deserve to be separated into another method? It may have to do some calculations before deciding that the parent's method should be called.

Or perhaps there is a different, better way to design it.

Comment: I don't get the problem here. You can still call `super` (even in different branches and even multiple times) in a very complex method, too.

Comment: `child_print` should call Parent's `print`. I think super just calls the method with the same name in the superclass. Or maybe I don't know how to use `super` properly. The reason why there is even a `child_print` is because I don't want to bloat the `print` method with things that aren't related to it, but is still required to determine whether to call the child's print or the parent's print.

Comment: Ah, sorry. It's already late here. ;) One moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Parent.instance_method(:print).bind(self).call
```

This is already pretty readable, but here's an explanation.

1. Get the `#print` method of the `Parent` class
2. Bind it to your current object
3. Call it

PS: You can even give arguments to `#call` and they will be relayed to the called method.

PPS: That said, such code almost always hints at an issue in your class design. You should try to avoid it whenever possible.

Comment: I didn't like what I was trying to do either, but I am modifying someone else's class and they've provided their interface and class designs as such and I'm stuck with trying to work with it. Some cases I need to call the parent's method, other cases I run my own. Could be solved with a bloated method, but I don't like large methods..